# Loop over a bunch of asynchronous operations and wait for them all to finish?

Tags: jquery, arrays, getjson

(Please don't mark as duplicate or at least point me to the correct answer as here I deal with multiple requests to form an array). I set up some url calls with the returned "data" values as an array. I plan to use this array to create the sum of all these values.

```
var data_num=[];
$.each(arr_urls, function( index, value ) {

  $.getJSON(arr_urls[index], function (data) {
      data_num.push(data);
  });
}); 
alert(data_num);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may already be familiar with *why* this doesn't work, and there are excellent explanations in [an oft linked duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call).  However, this isn't *entirely* a duplicate.  Because you're not asking this:

> How do I return the response from an asynchronous operation?

You're asking something more like this:

> How do I loop over a bunch of asynchronous operations and wait for them all to finish?

For that, you'd first need to put them into an array.  Something like this:

```
var my_promises = [];
var data_num = [];
$.each(arr_urls, function( index, value ) {
  my_promises.push($.getJSON(arr_urls[index], function (data) {
      data_num.push(data);
  }));
});
```

This should give you an array called `promises` which holds references to the currently-executing asynchronous operations.  Now you just need to wait for them all to complete.  Something like this:

```
$.when.apply($, my_promises).then(function() {
    alert(data_num);
});
```

This should apply the `.when()` function to the entire array of promises, executing the callback only when that entire array has completed.

Answer (score -1):

I will assume you can't do that server side (which would be the best thing to do).

Okay, **First things first:** Why are you doing `$.getJSON(arr_urls[index]`? If you want to do use `$.each`, you should use `value`, or even better: Using a **for** loop

```
for (var i = arr_urls.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
     arr_urls[i]
}
```

Also, why don't you try doing a `console.log(data)` to see on the JavaScript console what is returning? Your browser console can even tell you if there was an error on the request to the sites URL.

Comment: Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).

Comment: Sorry, i'm still very new here. Still getting the hang of it. But thanks for the links, i will take care.